# Is "bullet" from "bite the bullet" an exaggerated metaphor?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I've learnt about this idiom and its meaning , but i don't know about its common use since i think the word "bullet" is used as an exageration for a painful task or or an unpleasant situation. What is the appropiate way to use it?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Could you please edit your post and tell us what your research said about the metaphor? When I learned it, it was in the context of biting an unfired bullet to reduce perceived pain when someone, say, set a bone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning and origin of "bite the bullet"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/247999/meaning-and-origin-of-bite-the-bullet)

Answer (score 0):

The story is that, back in the days when your buddy rather than an ER surgeon would remove a bullet in your arm, you'd be handed a bare bullet (this was before cartridges, so it was a chunk of bare lead) and told to bite it, to help you deal with the pain.

Comment: Well, it would have been a field surgeon. See the photo in the duplicate thread.